# Fastest way to find the smallest number in a changing list in a loop in Python 3

Tags: python-3.x, list, loops, tuples, min

Given a list of 2-tuples `[(b,(x,y))]` which is manipualted every iteration a loop (`list.remove` and `list.append`). In every iteration the smallest number is requested and removed. At the moment im using `min(list)` to find the tuple with the smallest `b` in every iteration.

The algorithm behaves quite slow for big datasets. What is the best way to find the smallest value in a list which is manipulated in every iteration?

Comment: Hi, do you have a small snippet of code that you illustrates what the particular use case? If, for instance, you are adding/removing one element at a time, it would be a lot faster to compute the minimum once and then just check how the minimum compares to what you removed/added.

Comment: yeah i thought about this too but the minimum value is removed in every iteration. In a sorted list i could take the second smallest element but i have no idea if that would be efficient to sort

Comment: An option is to use a heap, to manage the values. Python has a standard implementation with `heapq` module. Then `heappop(q)` would always pop off the min value. And `heappush(q, (b, (x, y)))` would push the new value into the heap.

Comment: Do you have to maintain the order of the list?

Comment: No i just need to pick and remove the smallest number of the list every iteration and add `n` numbers to the list

Answer (score 2):

If you're *always* removing the smallest element in the list, you should be using a sorted list rather than an arbitrarily ordered one.

That way, the minimum will *always* be found at the head of the list.

The standard Python list is not sorted unless you insert at specific points yourself. However, there are plenty of implementations of sorted collections that you can use, such as the (pure Python) [Python sorted containers](http://www.grantjenks.com/docs/sortedcontainers/).

Comment: Note: the standard `heapq` module would maintain a standard python list in an known order, good for a priority queue.

Comment: as far as i udnerstood using a heap is not the best way here because i need to search and delete elements in the middle of the list nearly every iteration. Or would a lazy delete a proper solution for this?

Comment: @niaR, there is no more 'middle of the list' processing when you use a heap. You stated you are removing the smallest item each iteration and that will now be in a known location.